# How to integrate two themes templates into CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can already integrate a single theme template easily into CodeIgniter, but how do I integrate two themes into it and separate them for customer and admin ?

Right now I only have the admin theme template extracted into the root folder of the project, now i need to integrate the customer theme.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: create one folder on your root for your customer theme, put all theme files into it.

create one $config variable in your config file to call the file like this:
$config['customer_theme'] = 'http://localhost/projrct-folder-name/customer';

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, in the localhost/project-folder, i have to the pass the link to the root folder or the customer theme folder?